# Source Code of .NET Controls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

how can i see source code of built in controls in visual studio offline?

Answer (score 3):

You can disassemble the IL into somewhat readable source code using Lutz Roeder's [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).  The local variable names won't be very descriptive, but you can get a good feel for what the program logic is.

You can also disassemble IL using the [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28VS.80%29.aspx) utility, but this is a bit more involved.

Answer (score 2):

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Note that this is *shared*-source, not open-source.  (You can't contribute code)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [Schabse Laks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) writes on downloading the sources at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx:

There is more info on the sourcecode at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

You can also configure the .NET debuggers to use http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols as a symbol server and step through the .NET 4.0 source code:

- [Steps for Visual Studio](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETFrameworkLibrarySourceCodeAvailableForViewing.aspx) by [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/aboutme.aspx)
- [A small fix for the order of debug symbols in Visual Studio 2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/refsourceserver/thread/63abf25a-4ca1-4ba1-b5a4-13af9b2091e0) by [Sorporbear](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Profile/en-US/?user=Sorporbear&referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/refsourceserver/thread/63abf25a-4ca1-4ba1-b5a4-13af9b2091e0&rh=PkUAU8ms3dXkyHjvotjx4fqXiPzRtHfXIFb8Yl/foCo%3d&sp=forums)
- [Steps for WinDbg](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/05/31/debugging-net-framework-4-0-without-source-code-using-windbg/) by [Naveen Srinivasan](http://naveensrinivasan.com/about/)

Note that downloading the sources in your debugger can be really slow the first time (lots of sources need to be downloaded, the server might be a bit busy, or your internet connection might be slow).

--jeroen